# Android app crashes when fcm is sent and app is open

Tags: android, firebase, service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase with my android app to send push notifications. When I send a message and the app is closed, the notification is received, the intent works and everything is fine. But when the app is open and I send a message, it crashes with this error from the `getColor()` method:

```
Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getColor(I)I in class Lcom/kinectafrica/android/service/FirebaseMessagingService; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.kinectafrica.android.service.FirebaseMessagingService' appears in /data/app/com.kinectafrica.android-1/base.apk)
com.kinectafrica.android.service.FirebaseMessagingService.sendNotification (FirebaseMessagingService.java:45)
com.kinectafrica.android.service.FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived (FirebaseMessagingService.java:33)
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzo ()
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzn ()
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzm ()
com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run ()
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

This is my `FirebaseMessagingService` class:

```
package com.kinectafrica.android.service;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.kinectafrica.android.R;
import com.kinectafrica.android.activity.SplashScreenActivity;

/**
 * Made by acefalobi on 5/16/2017.
 */

public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    int notifyId = 0;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d("Service", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d("Service", "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("Service", "Message notification: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    }

    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isNotify", true);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
                .setColor(getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                .setContentTitle("Kinect")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(uri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notifyId, builder.build());
        notifyId++;
    }
}
```

Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: log cat of crash plzz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
.setColor(getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
```

Is causing your problem.  Since you are calling it within your FirebaseMessagingService class, Android is looking for the method there.  You may have to reference an Activity context in order to use it.